# libmemcached problem

Tags: c, linux, libmemcache

when i run the libmemcached example code on my ubuntu, it gave me the error "undefined reference to `memcached_create'", anyone can help ? thanks

```
#include <libmemcached/memcached.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {  
  //memcached_servers_parse (char *server_strings); 
  memcached_server_st *servers = NULL;
  memcached_st *memc;
  memcached_return rc;
  char *key= "keystring";
  char *value= "keyvalue";

  memc= memcached_create(NULL);
  servers= memcached_server_list_append(servers, "localhost", 11211, &rc);   rc= memcached_server_push(memc, servers);

  if (rc == MEMCACHED_SUCCESS)
    fprintf(stderr,"Added server successfully\n");   else
    fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't add server: %s\n",memcached_strerror(memc, rc));

  rc= memcached_set(memc, key, strlen(key), value, strlen(value), (time_t)0, (uint32_t)0);

  if (rc == MEMCACHED_SUCCESS)
    fprintf(stderr,"Key stored successfully\n");   else
    fprintf(stderr,"Couldn't store key: %s\n",memcached_strerror(memc, rc));

  return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `-lmemcached` to GCC.  This tells it to link to the `libmemcached.so` shared library.

Comment: when i run gcc 3gbbn.c -lmemcached, it works. that's to say, my origin problem is: the code found the header file, but the header file cant find the .so file

Comment: @sharp, yes, the header file only provides the compiler with prototypes.  It does not tell the linker where the functions' implementations are.

Comment: i have same problem and also added -lmemcached but still it's showing same error

Comment: @PHPConnect, you may not have the actual library installed.  What operating system and version are you running?

Comment: I have ubuntu system and i have installed libmemcached with prefix in "/opt/memcached"

Answer (score 0):

When I built the library (libmemcached), it only builds the static library and when I am linking my program ( mentioned above ), it gives me

```
$ gcc MyMemClient.c  -o MyMemClient -L/usr/local/lib/libmemcached.a
/tmp/ccQEXVjv.o:MyMemClient.c:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `_memcached_create'
/tmp/ccQEXVjv.o:MyMemClient.c:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `_memcached_server_list_append'
//ccQEXVjv.o:MyMemClient.c:(text+0x6d): undefined reference to `_memcached_server_push'
/tmp/ccQEXVjv.o:MyMemClient.c:(.text+0xc1): undefined reference to `_memcached_strerror'
/tmpccQEXVjv.o:MyMemClient.c:(.text+0x12a): undefined reference to `_memcached_set'
/tmp/ccQEXVjv.o:MyMemClient.c:(.text+0x170): undefined reference to `_memcached_strerror'
/tmp/ccQEXVjv.o:MyMemClient.c:(.text+0x199): undefined reference to `_memcached_server_free'
//ccQEXVjv.o:MyMemClient.c:(.text+0x1a4): undefined reference to `_memcached_free'
ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0):

1. open your terminal and change directory to your libmemcached which is uncompressed.
2. type `./configure`
3. type `make`
4. in your C project, Right click and select "Properties". In "linker" add "libmemcached.so" library and remember to add Library directory (links to your directory contains libmemcached.so).